# Firebase/Firestore find documents that have a field in a given array

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase collection whose documents have a field phone_number.

I want to query firebase for all the documents that have the field phone_number in a array given by me!

Is it possible to do it in one query or should I iterate through all the documents and do it?

Something like this:

```
db.collection('users').where( 'phoneNumber', "in", data.phoneNumbers);
// data.phoneNumbers is an array
```

Note!!! I'm doing this inside a google cloud function!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array query support only works the other way around: when you have a single value and you want to find documents that contain that value in a field's array.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership

```js
var results = docsRef.where('phoneNumbers', 'array-contains',
  '555-123-4567');
```

In your case you would need to loop over your list of phone numbers and run a query for each one of them.

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible using a recently added [`in` operator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any):

```js
citiesRef.where('region', 'in',
    [['west_coast', 'east_coast']]);
```