# To retrieve specific field without document in Firestore

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a collection named sample which contains 4-5 documents with a randomly generated document id. Each document contains a specific field "msg_id" that I want to retrieve. I don't want to retrieve it using the document id. Is there any way to do that?

I tried using the following script :

```
    const db = getFirestore();
    
    const queryref = await db.collection('sample').where("msg_id", "==", 1234).get();
```

But I'm not able to see the data

Please find the table below:
[image]

Comment: I don't think it is possible to get field value without a document id, but you can fetch documents with specific field.you can check this [link1](https://codingshower.com/firestore-get-all-documents-where-a-specific-field-exists-or-does-not-exist/), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55340031/firebase-firestore-find-documents-that-have-a-field-in-a-given-array) & [link3](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Query.html#select)

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, your logic seems right but I think the issue you're having is you're mixing two different versions which results in an error. `getFirestore()` is the Web version 9 (modular version) and `db.collection('sample').where("msg_id", "==", 1234).get();` is the syntax for the Web version 8 (namespaced version).

I would assume that you're using the Web version 9 as you have the `getFirestore()` initialization. See sample code below to get the documents using the where query with a specific field `msg_id`:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { collection, query, where, getDocs, getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
  // Your firebase config.
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);

const q = query(collection(db, "sample"), where("msg_id", "==", 1234));

const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});
```

Let me know if you're using the web 8 version instead.

For more information you may checkout this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries).